# Sorting strings and create case based on keywords

Tags: php, string, loops, if-statement

I need to check the gmail in-box and read the email body of each email and create a case in CRM based on Keywords 'Billing and Loading', I have a working code for reading mails from Gmail but sorting has been the issue.

I have this code

```
 foreach($emails as $email) {

        $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($connection,$email);
        $message= imap_fetchbody($connection , $email,1);

        if (preg_match('/Bill|load/', $message)) {
            if (strpos($message, 'Bill')) {
                echo 'billing related issue';
            }elseif (strpos($message, 'load')) {
                echo 'Loading related issue';
            }
        }else echo 'doesn\'t exists</br>';
     }
```

This code checks all the mails, finds the keywords but it checks for either Billing or Loading, not for both,. Please help me.

Comment: There is no point in using `preg_match` here. Use `strpos` to check if there is `Bill`. Check if there is `load`. Store the results in separate variables. Check their values and write appropriate logic.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Sorry,. That is what I'm not being able to do, I am not understanding how to store them in separate variables and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of `preg_match()`here. `strpos()` will work in desired way:-

```
 foreach($emails as $email) {
    $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($connection,$email);
    $message= imap_fetchbody($connection , $email,1);
    if (strpos($message, 'Bill')!== false && strpos($message, 'load') === false) {
        echo 'billing related issue';
    }else if (strpos($message, 'Bill') === false && strpos($message, 'load') !== false) {
        echo 'Loading related issue';
    }else if(strpos($message, 'Bill') !== false && strpos($message, 'load') !== false){
        echo 'Loading/Billing related issue';
    }else echo 'does\'t exists</br>';
 }
```

Comment: @SugarAPI  glad to help you.:):):)

Comment: Marked, Thank you